# How do I make a deep copy of a vector in C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++, c++-winrt

I have a private `IObservableVector` of `UIElements` implemented through a `single_threaded_observable_vector` in my C++/WinRT WinUI3 project. Let's call it `m_precious_vector`. I have a getter function of `PreciousVector` that I want to return a deep copy of `m_precious_vector` from so no client could modify `m_precious_vector` without going through my separate setter function, but I can't seem to figure out how to create anything other than a shallow copy.

Please leave a comment if I should be leaving any more info :)

Edit: More info as promised, thank you commenters!

I first tried to see if the getter would return by reference or value. I was able to edit the vector itself from the getter, so I assumed it was a reference (I have a code snippet of what I did there further down the question). I tried making a deep copy by doing below in ProjContent::PreciousVector():

```
# ProjContent.h
# Some header files... 

namespace winrt::Proj::implementation
{
    struct ProjContent : ProjContentT<ProjContent>
    {
    public:
        # ... other code ...

        winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItem> PreciousVector();
    
    private:
        # ... other code ...

        winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItem> m_preciousVector;
    };
}


# ProjContent.cpp
# some header files...

namespace muxc
{
    using namespace winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;
};

# ... more other code ...

winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<muxc::NavigationViewItem> ProjContent::PreciousVector()
{
    return winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<muxc::NavigationViewItem> {m_preciousVector};
}
```

The naming is not the best, thank you for bearing with me.

I believed this would create a shallow copy because I tested using this getter from another class that is in the same namespace and edited the vector from the returned value directly and observed the size change from another call of PreciousVector().Size().

```
# ProjViewModel.h
# Some header files... 

namespace winrt::Proj::implementation
{
    struct ProjViewModel : ProjViewModelT<ProjViewModel>
    {
    public:
        # ... other code ...

    private:
        # ... other code ...
        Proj::ProjContent m_projContent{ nullptr };
    };
}


# ProjViewModel.cpp
# Some header files
using namespace winrt;

namespace muxc
{
    using namespace winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;
};

namespace winrt::Proj::implementation
{
    # ... other code ...

    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ProjViewModel::AddContent()
    {
        co_await winrt::resume_foreground(m_dispatcher);  # m_dispatcher is tied to the UI thread
        # using the debugger, size is 0 here.
        int size = m_proj_content.PreciousVector().Size();
        muxc::WebView2 worldWV;
        m_proj_content.PreciousVector().Append(worldWV);
        # using the debugger, size is 1 here.
        size = m_proj_content.PreciousVector().Size();
    }
```

I wanted to try the "new" keyword but that is now deprecated and it would not let me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: How do you make a shallow copy? How did you try to make it deep? What concrete observations led you to believe your attempt failed?